# Administrator login and spectator login

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to build an iOS app using swift. I'm stuck at a crucial part in my development though. I'm trying to make an app that allows users to login as an administrator or a spectator.

Logging in as the administrator allows the user to enter data into parse database that pushes to the spectator to see during runtime.

The problem is that I need to ask the user to pick which login to use, and then the app will be set up to suite the needs of each type of login. Basically creating 2 apps in 1.

Is this possible or should I create a web base administer connecting to the spectator using the app?

Answer (score 0):

I would no do that (also for security reasons). If an administrator should also have the possibilities to check out how does it look like, you should be doing this AFTER you already logged in as administrator.

So:

Single Login for both privileges.

Login is administrator - Option to change his "privileges mode" - > switch to spectator

Login as spectator -> Still everything als spectator.

This is how lot of professional software solutions handle that.